# NSXMLParser - what is the original data?

Tags: cocoa

I have created `NSXMLParser` object using the following code:

```
- (void) foo:(NSMutableString *)string
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

and sometimes I get errors after running the parser (delegate method is being called upon error):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    LOGE(@"XML parser error in line:%ld column:%ld. Retrying..", [parser lineNumber], [parser columnNumber]);
    [parser abortParsing];
    [parser parse];
}
```

How can I extract back the original `string` or `data` from the parser when I get errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use those pointers later, then it is your responsibility to store pointers to those objects, not the parser.

The parser never has knowledge of string, as it is never passed to it. It would also be horribly inefficient if the parser held on to a pointer of the data.